# New install of 15.04 with Windows 7 but Window says file is missing so wont open

Tags: wubi

I've just install 15.04 and rebooted to go into system but I get the following error.
File: /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr is missing.
status: Oxc0000001
the message recommended rebooting with the Windows 7 install disk and run repair on my PC. This I did but it could not auto repair the problem.
Any ideas how I can fix this annoying problem.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using UEFI? If you are, you've made a big mistake.

Comment: Wubi didn't work with 14.10. It wasn't fixed for 15.04. The only way to use it that I know of is to get [hakuna_matata's custom version linked from here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2251986&p=13276572#post13276572) (his works with UEFI as well). Note for all intents and purposes hakuna_matata is the Wubi developer now. Unless you really want Wubi and are prepared to go with the community supported version, you should just do a normal dual boot.  Or use a VM It's not very complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I ignored the WUBI and install straight from the disk and on the fourth attempt it finally worked and I can now dual boot. So happy person I am. Thanks again for all the advse.